# How to build ACE 6.0(network library) as static?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, network-programming, ace

ACE supplied solution file for Visual Studio, and there were solution files for static and dynamic liking.(ACE.sln and ACE_static.sln)

After they release 6.0, there was no static.sln anymore.
I can't understand. Why did they remove solution file for static? Is there a reason?
I'm putting predefined values for static build by myself. It's very annoying me.

Is there other convenient way?

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to use the dll ?

Comment: @DumbCoder I don't want to let end-users know that we use ace. Yes, it's not a big deal, most of users even don't care about that. But I prefer hiding way. Another reason. When we deploy files to client machines by autoupdaters, if a dll is using it's annoying autoupdaters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just posted the same question on the comp.soft-sys.ace newsgroup where I got some help from one of the ACE developers:

[ACE 6.0 Static Builds](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.ace/browse_thread/thread/1eb2a24108d2b1c1#)

Basically there's a Perl tool called MPC that's distributed with ACE that they use to compile all the build files (I haven't gotten it to work yet but then that's probably just something I'm doing wrong :)

Anyway if you open up the .sln files in Notepad you'll actually see the MPC command line used to build it near the top in the comments.

Comment: Turns out I needed to run the mwc.pl script from within the directory that contains the ACE.mwc file! Knew it was something simple :)  Anyway it works fine now...

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to compile ACE 6.3.1 on Win32. Instructions given at http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/DOC_ROOT/ACE/ACE-INSTALL.html were bit confusing for me as there was no file ace.sln as mentioned in instructions. To generate the sln file, followed below steps using windows cmd -

1. Set env variable ACE_ROOT to complete path of ACE-src-6.3.1\ACE_wrappers
2. go to dir %ACE_ROOT%\ace
3. Run cmd as I was interested in VS 2010 solution file

`perl %ACE_ROOT%\bin\mwc.pl -type vc10 ace.mwc`

This has generated solution file inside ACE_ROOT/ace dir and I was able to compile the solution using VS2010 express edition.